# May the Pi2 have a MongoDB 2.6 bamp, please?

Tags: mongodb

Fellow Raspberreans:

Please correct me whether or not I'm wrong, but the source to MongoDB cannot fit inside Raspbian, or compile on ARM.

Our best workaound is https://github.com/RickP/mongopi , except that source code is stale - version 2.1.1.

I happen to be developing using the mighty Pi2 as a desktop, with JetBrains Idea editor, Django, and Postgresql, and fixing the mongo would save me from learning how to remote the mongo to another server.

Has anyone broken the Pi2 barrier for a more modern source of MongoDB?

Comment: You would be better off installing it on another machine. Mongo 32 bit is deprecated and only for development at this point. Running it on the Pi with the minimal resources available will hamper performance (the main reason for utilizing a noSQL db). Even if you ran it on your local desktop, it should provide better performance and user experience. Moving the data and connecting to a remote server is not that difficult.

Comment: Great. Mongo doubtless uses C++/STL/Boost `traits<>` agonizingly correctly, still needs to "support" 32 bits as a client. I'm sure the next Pi will be 64 bit...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm confirming Steve's short-term answer, here. The committee thought opening a mongo to external clients might be ... hard. Instead, you simply get on a non-Pi console and cast this magical spell:

```
sudo nano +11 /etc/mongodb.conf
```

make the `bind_ip` lines look like this:

```
# bind_ip = 127.0.0.1  #  oh aren't WE the prude?
bind_ip = 0.0.0.0  #  hello, cloud
```

Then add the `host=` option to your client with the right server name or IP, `restart` that server, and it works. We all know some systems that make you fantasize about taking the entire low-rise full of programmers responsible for "system security" hostage before you're ever even halfway that far...

So now that this page is SEO complete, for the newbs with excess personal electronics crowd, we await another hardware rev, or one of those highly [parallel](https://www.parallella.org/) $99 system-on-a-boards also available these days.